# I dont know what the following does

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I don't understand what this code does

```
useEffect(() => {    
    document.addEventListener('input', event => {
      if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'textarea') {
        return
      }
      autoExpand(event.target)
    }, false)
  }, [])
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: I suggest to read about `useEffect` hook, please find it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: when is the useEffect hook initiated?

Comment: @SnigdhaReddyPulim Before the component renders. Because there is an empty array as the second argument to useEffect, this is the only time that code will run.

Comment: Please update your question with a title that summarizes the specific problem, and what you've tried to solve it yourself. Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to explain what you have in your code.

About [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook you can read in the documentation:

> The Effect Hook lets you perform side effects in function components.

In your case the dependency array is empty `[]` which means it is called only once when the functional component loaded. Similarly like in class based component but a combined life-cycle events, from the docs:

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of `useEffect` Hook as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` combined.

If you have an object in the dependency array, it will trigger again the passed function once it is changing.

I suggest to read further about `useEffect` hook in more details below: 
 https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

It will help you to understand deeper. I hope that helps!